# symfony 3 - translations not working in prod

Tags: php, translation, symfony

im developping symfony 3 project and i have a issue with the translations.
In my dev envioment, the translations works fine but in Prod envioment, i get the translations variable.

Im working with twig and i translate text like this:

```
{% trans %}frontend.search.label.title.search{% endtrans %}
```

This variable, get the text from: 
App/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml

```
frontend.search.label.title.search: Search a station
frontend.search.label.select.status: Status
frontend.search.label.button.search: Search
frontend.search.label.button.createstation: Create new station
frontend.search.label.button.managenewfields: Manage new fields
frontend.search.input.error: Please enter search criteria
```

[This is Dev envioment result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdfgQ.png)

But when i go to Prod envioment, the text show like this:

[Prod envioment result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GPxW.png)

I set the language of user when they log in with this code:

```
$this->session->set('_locale', $user->getlanguage()->getLanguageCode());
```

This is the listener:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/EventListener/UserLocaleListener.php
namespace loginBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

/**
 * Stores the locale of the user in the session after the
 * login. This can be used by the LocaleListener afterwards.
 */
class UserLocaleListener
{   
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    public $em;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $session;

    public function __construct(Session $session, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event
     */
    public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        if (null !== $user->getlanguage()->getLanguageCode() && $user->getlanguage()->getLanguageCode() != '00') {
            $this->session->set('_locale', $user->getlanguage()->getLanguageCode());
        }else{
            $em = $this->em;
            $DefaultLang = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:M01Language')->findOneBylanguageDefault(1);
            $this->session->set('_locale', $DefaultLang->getLanguageCode());
        }
    }
}
```

in my config.yml i have this code for translations:

```
/* .......... */
parameters:
    locale: en
    app.locales: en|es|fr
    locale_supported: ['en','es','fr']

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
/* .......... */
```

Help please and sorry for my bad english.

[SOLVED]

I remove all files and folders in var/cache/Prod except the folder with name "doctrine".

Refresh and it work!!

Thank you.

Comment: Clear prod cache? `rm -rf app/cache/prod`

Comment: If i remove it, i get this error:
Warning: require(..\AccessibleStations\var\cache\prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__AppBundleEntityM01Language.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ..\AccessibleStations\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Proxy\AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 209

Comment: drop the prod and dev folder manually. Then try again